# ExceptionHandler not handle exception

Tags: java, exception, kotlin, jwt

I have Exception:

```
open class CustomException(open val code: String, override val message: String) : RuntimeException(message)
```

Other custom exceptions inherits from it:

```
class DataAccessException(override val code: String, override val message: String) : CustomException(code, message)

class NoMatchingValueException(override val code: String, override val message: String) : CustomException(code, message)

class ApiException(override val code: String, override val message: String) : CustomException(code, message)

class JwtAuthenticationException(override val code: String, override val message: String) : CustomException(code, message)
```

`ExceptionHandler` handles them. Now it looks like there:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = [DataAccessException::class])
fun handle(exception: DataAccessException): ResponseEntity<AbstractDto> =
        ResponseEntity.ok(AbstractDto(exception.code, exception.message))

@ExceptionHandler(value = [NoMatchingValueException::class])
fun handle(exception: NoMatchingValueException): ResponseEntity<AbstractDto> =
        ResponseEntity.ok(AbstractDto(exception.code, exception.message))

@ExceptionHandler(value = [ApiException::class])
fun handle(exception: ApiException): ResponseEntity<AbstractDto> =
        ResponseEntity.ok(AbstractDto(exception.code, exception.message))

@ExceptionHandler(value = [JwtAuthenticationException::class])
fun handle(exception: JwtAuthenticationException): ResponseEntity<AbstractDto> =
        ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(AbstractDto(StatusCode.UNAUTHORIZED.name, exception.message!!))
```

All custom exception correctly handles by ExceptionHandler, exclude `JwtAuthenticationException`

This exception throws only in one case, while validates JWM-token.

```
    try {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getExpiration().after(new Date());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new JwtAuthenticationException(StatusCode.UNAUTHORIZED.name(), "JWT token is invalid");
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
        throw new JwtAuthenticationException(StatusCode.UNAUTHORIZED.name(), "JWT token expired.");
    }
```

In this way, there are 3 stacktraces logs in console:

```
JwtAuthenticationException: JWT token expired.
...
ERROR 22059 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

JwtAuthenticationException: JWT token expired.
...
ERROR 22059 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

JwtAuthenticationException: JWT token expired.
```

Frontend reseives only

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
```

Please tell me, what wrong.

P.S. Full StackTrace:

> xpendence.exceptions.JwtAuthenticationException: JWT token
>   expired.  at
>   ru.xpendence.config.security.jwt.JwtTokenProvider.validate(JwtTokenProvider.java:84)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   ru.xpendence.config.security.jwt.JwtTokenFilter.doFilter(JwtTokenFilter.java:34)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_212]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_212]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
>
> 2019-07-14 17:04:38.791 ERROR 24060 --- [nio-8081-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
>
> ru.xpendence.exceptions.JwtAuthenticationException: JWT token
>   expired.  at
>   ru.xpendence.config.security.jwt.JwtTokenProvider.validate(JwtTokenProvider.java:84)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   ru.xpendence.config.security.jwt.JwtTokenFilter.doFilter(JwtTokenFilter.java:34)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:348)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:173)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_212]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_212]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
>
> 2019-07-14 17:04:38.791 ERROR 24060 --- [nio-8081-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing
>   ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
>
> ru.xpendence.exceptions.JwtAuthenticationException: JWT token
>   expired.  at
>   ru.xpendence.config.security.jwt.JwtTokenProvider.validate(JwtTokenProvider.java:84)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   ru.xpendence.config.security.jwt.JwtTokenFilter.doFilter(JwtTokenFilter.java:34)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:348)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:173)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_212]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_212]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]

Comment: You don't have any exception handler for JwtAuthenticationException. As simple as that.

Comment: You would need to have a exception handler for JwtAuthenticationException and send back the response for that as required.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry pasted old code. I have needed exception handling method.

Comment: @MadhuBhat sorry pasted old code. I have needed exception handling method.

Comment: Where is the code throwing the exception located? When and where is it called? What is the exact and complete exception stack trace?

Comment: It located in ControllerAdvisor class, it called in Component. I added full StackTrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is not thrown from a Spring controller, so it can't be caught by a `ControllerAdvice`, which, as its name and its documentation indicates, advises controllers, not filters.

Comment: Don't throw an exception. do whatever you need to do with the HttpServletResponse passed as argument to the filter method. Note (and it's also true for all your exception handlers), that sending back a response with an OK status is really not the appropriate thing to do. 401 is the correct status code to signal an euthentication problem.